# Can I leave my computer turned off for several years?

Tags: power, desktop-computer

I'm planning to work abroad for several years and I can't bring my trusty PC along. I'm gonna buy a laptop and I'll possibly only come back home after 5 years. So my question is:

#### Is it OK to leave my computer turned off for several years?

Or should I ask a friend to turn it on from time to time? I'm thinking about sealing it off in plastic and leaving it turned off the whole time.

For specifics, my PC is a desktop computer, Intel processor (Core i7) and Motherboard (DP55WB), has regular internal and external HDDs and an Nvidia graphic card. I usually use it a few hours a day. The only problem I can think of so far is the battery of the motherboard (for the BIOS) dying out, but this is cheap to replace.

Comment: But there might be a misunderstanding: my question is whether I can leave the power turned off the whole time, so powering it down is what I want to know if is safe

Comment: This might be random, but still I have generally noticed that when I leave my PC off for a long time, I almost certainly need to re-seat some components like RAM sticks or reconnect SATA connectors before everything would perfectly power on again.

Comment: @rajeev I've also noticed this! Maybe the connectors get kind of rusted due to humidity? @ JakeGould Thanks for the answer! You're right, I'm backing up the data

Comment: Putting in a bunch of silica gel packs (in your PC's case and the bag the PC will be in) sounds like a very good idea.

Comment: An SSD is quite possibly goig to loose data if continuously powered down for 5 years.  This ("spec related" link) is an unrealistically bad scenario - but you are talking about 5 years - which is a very long time.   Have you considered backing up your hard drive and selling your PC - in 5 years time it will be considered pretty old and not of much value - especially as your motherboard dates back to 2009.

Comment: Thank you all for the insightful comments! @ confetti, that's a great idea! @ davidgo thanks a lot for the info! I think there's something wrong with the link, could you post it again? Fortunately, my HDD isn't SSD. I did consider selling it, but it's 9 years old and kind of rusted, it wouldn't sell for much, though it fits me perfectly. I'll also need it if I come back home from time to time