# How to start a computer that has been off for years

Tags: hard-drive, boot, data-recovery, desktop-computer

I have a desktop computer (circa 2011?) that has been turned off and unplugged for five years. My memory is it worked fine when I shut it off.

The hard drive (HDD/spinning disk) is partitioned to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 7.

After losing a backup, this is the last place where some old pictures may be found. I want to maximize my chance of success in recovering them.

Is there anything I can do before, during, or after plugging it in and turning it on to maximize the chance of success? Could attempting to boot the machine damage the drive (and if so, would it be best to move it to a known good machine and get the data that way)?

I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1348305/can-i-leave-my-computer-turned-off-for-several-years) about preparation, but I haven't run into anything about what to do after.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'd be inclined to replace the thermal paste on the CPU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do anything out of the ordinary. A computer is simply designed to turn on and start.

So do this (and for any electronic that has been OFF for years): Plug it in and leave it sit for say (an hour). Less is fine, more not necessary.

After an hour, turn it on and see if it starts.

Watch and smell carefully.

It may start; it may not; the disk might start; the disk might not. BIOS firmware settings may be lost or may not be.

Try as above and see what happens.

My observations come in part by having a couple of pieces of very old electronic gear (50 and 65 years old). They still run fine (no drives in them), but the 50 year machine does have integrated circuits in it.

Answer (score 4):

After 11 years and five of those unplugged, the CMOS battery (the coin cell on the motherboard - usually a CR2032) is most likely drained, meaning the BIOS settings are lost.

This is not a problem per se, but it can cause the operating system(s) to not boot if for example the Boot Order is not correctly set anymore or if the Mass Storage Mode has been changed (motherboards of this vintage are notorious for not having AHCI as default, which can cause problems if Windows has originally been installed in AHCI mode).

Answer (score 1):

attempting to boot the machine is unlikely to damage the drive any more then poweri g it up while dorectly plugged in to another machine.

If you live in a cold or or damp area, ensuring the machine is brought up to room temperature and a moderate humidity (40-60%) before turning it on might increase the already high chance it will "just work".

I'd be inclined to just power it up, but if you are particularly worried you could unplug the drive, power up the computer, then - if it starts up, power it down and plug in the drive - This will allow the caps in the psu to recharge and provide slightly cleaner power on startup.  If you are even more worried you could remove the drive and power it from a USB adaptor - but this replaces one set of risks with another.

In short, you should be fine. If not, there is little you can really do that will make a big difference to the outcome.